# when sorting list without using built in functions like min,max and sort, index error when using while 1 instead of while timelist2

Tags: python

```
timelist2 = [11.56, 11.14, 11.85, 10.2, 10.31, 10.95, 10.56, 10.66, 10.33, 11.34, 10.4, 10.45, 10.82, 10.46, 11.11, 10.98]
new_list=[]
while timelist2:
  minimum = timelist2[0]
  for i in timelist2:
    if i<minimum:
      minimum = i

  new_list.append(minimum)  

  timelist2.remove(minimum)
print(new_list)
```

but if I change line 3 of the code to `while 1:` , I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    minimum = timelist2[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't understand what's the difference between while 1 and while timelist2, aren't they both the same as while True?

Comment: `while timelist2:` means "while the list is not empty".  Your second version is an infinite loop, that keeps on trying to find the minimum value and remove it even after there are no more values to be found or removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `while 1` is not the same that `while timelist2`.

The sentence `while timelist2` will be True until it's empty.

For the second option: `while timelist2`:

- In each iteration you are removing 1 element from timelist2.
- When timelist2 is empty, your code jumps from the cycle
- No error is throwed

For the first option: `while 1`:

- In each iteration you are removing 1 element from timelist2.
- When timelist2 is empty, your code will not jump from the cycle because the condition 1 is always True, and when you try access the `timelist2[0]`, it throws an error, because timelist2 is empty and have no elements.
- Even you protect with a `if` to just remove when `timelist2` is not empty, you have another error, because you have no `break condition` and it's gonna be an infinite cycle.